# (SQL) Union combination with additional data

Tags: mysql, sql-server, union

I use a database program called Agility by WiSys at my job. I had an unusual occurrence where part the data I needed was found in one column of a specific table and the rest was in another column in another table.

I used a UNION to combine these tables, but I have found that I cannot add any more data needed for the rest of my report. When I do, I receive a Error Message stating: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT OR EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Basically, the UNION works as needed, I have combined my data into one column, however, I cannot call any additional data needed in the query because the UNION prevents that data from being called.

Here is my query without the additional data I need:

```
SELECT table1_sql.UnionColumn1, 
FROM   table1_sql 
UNION 
SELECT table2_sql.UnionColumn2 AS CombinedColumn 
FROM   table2_sql 
ORDER  BY CombinedColumn
```

I need to have the UNION with these extra columns in my report as well:

```
SELECT table1_sql.UnionColumn1,
   table1_sql.ExtraColumn1,
   table1_sql.ExtraColumn2,
   table1_sql.ExtraColumn3,
   table1_sql.ExtraColumn4
FROM   table1_sql
UNION
SELECT table2_sql.UnionColumn2 AS CombinedColumn
FROM   table2_sql
ORDER  BY CombinedColumn
```

An example of the data that I am trying to retrieve would be:
[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO2Io.png) Where Order_No is the data that I want to join via UNION and everything else is data that is also needed but not allowed with a UNION.

The program Agility is not as robust as other programs, so I am somewhat limited in my ability to complete this reports using alternatives to UNION. Please advice.

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? It would be helpful in fleshing out your question.

Comment: @Mureinik I used a UNION to get combine two lists of order numbers, along with that list, I need a sales date, item number and item quantity. I'll add a better example to my question, but a brief example table would be like: | Order_No | Date | Item_No | Qty_Sold |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you the complete story. When using a union BOTH queries MUST have the same number of columns. You can work with it by simply adding some hard coded NULLS.

```
SELECT table1_sql.UnionColumn1,
   table1_sql.ExtraColumn1,
   table1_sql.ExtraColumn2,
   table1_sql.ExtraColumn3,
   table1_sql.ExtraColumn4
FROM   table1_sql
UNION
SELECT table2_sql.UnionColumn2 AS CombinedColumn
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
FROM   table2_sql
ORDER  BY CombinedColumn
```

Please note you will have to order by UnionColumn1 because the column names in the second query are not the name of the columns in the final result set. Only the names from the first query.

Comment: That got me over the roadblock I had! It never occurred to me to input NULL on the other side of the UNION, just because I thought the error demanded some sort of data balance and I never realized that NULL would do the job. Thank you.